# What is wrong with this sql query to cause this error?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join

What is wrong with this query?

```
" where mh.parent_id = ? "+ (roleIds != null ? " or mh.role_id in (" + roleIds + ")" : "") +
```

Error Message:

> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select u.id,u.user_id,count(distinct pf.id),IfNULL(upm.grievance_autoassign_enable,true)  from users u  inner join user_roles ur on ur.user_id=u.id  left outer join user_preference_management upm on u.id = upm.id  inner  join management_hierarchy mh on mh.child_id = u.id or mh.role_id =ur.role_id  left outer join ( jbpm4_task  jt  inner join process_flow pf on pf.pid = jt.execution_id_ and pf.grievance_mgmt_id is not null)  on jt.assignee_ = u.user_id  where mh.parent_id = ?  or mh.role_id in ({role_id=2},{role_id=4},{role_id=1},{role_id=8},{role_id=38},{role_id=22},{role_id=69}) group by u.id,u.user_id  order by count(pf.id) ]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=2},{role_id=4},{role_id=1},{role_id=8},{role_id=38},{role_id=22},{role_id=69}) ' at line 1

Comment: What type is `roleIds`? From the SQL in the error message, it looks like it might be a list of some kind of object? You will need to turn it into a comma-separated list of just the numbers, without `{role_id=}`.

Comment: Where is the rest of the query and the Java code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, heres teh entire query,

Comment: "select u.id,u.user_id,count(distinct pf.id),IfNULL(upm.grievance_autoassign_enable,true) "+
    " from users u "+  
    " inner join user_roles ur on ur.user_id=u.id " +
    " left outer join user_preference_management upm on u.id = upm.id "+
    " inner  join management_hierarchy mh on mh.child_id = u.id or mh.role_id =ur.role_id "+  
    " left outer join ( jbpm4_task  jt "+

Comment: " inner join process_flow pf on pf.pid = jt.execution_id_ and pf.grievance_mgmt_id is not null)  on jt.assignee_ = u.user_id "+
    " where mh.parent_id = ? "+ (roleIds != null ? " or mh.role_id in (" + roleIds + ")" : "") +
    " group by u.id,u.user_id  order by count(pf.id) ";

Comment: This isthe fuction used to call the querry 
public List<GWTDBSummary> getGrievanceAssignedTaskCount(Integer id  ) {
  List<Integer> roles = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select role_id from user_roles where user_id = ?" , new Object[]{id});
  String roleIds= "";
  for (int i= 0; i < roles.size(); i++)
  { 
   if (roles.get(i) != null) {
    if(i!=0){
     roleIds += "," + String.valueOf(roles.get(i)) ;
    }else{
     roleIds += String.valueOf(roles.get(i));
    }
   }
  }

Comment: It is probably this: `mh.role_id in ({role_id=2},{role_id=4},{role_id=1},{role_id=8},{role_id=38},{role_id=22},{role_id=69})`. Do you mean `mh.role_id IN (2,4,1,8,38,22,69)`

Comment: Please edit the question to include those, rather than posting them as comments; makes it easier to see the whole question at once. Also please consider adding newlines to the query, as it requires a lot of scrolling right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your string `roleIds`, which appear to be in JSON notation. The correct syntax for a SQL `where..in` statement would be comma-separated.

Make your query look more like this:

```
 . . . where mh.parent_id = ? or mh.role_id in (2,4,1,8,38,22,69) group by . . .
```